# Присвоение аргумента

Tags: python, python-2.x

Извините, я новичок. Подскажите плиз как из трех чисел, например 10, 20, 30 мне создать аргумент для среднего числа, то бишь для числа "20".
Для чисел 10 и 30 я сделал так:

```
 a=float(sys.argv[1])
 b=float(sys.argv[2])
 c=float(sys.argv[3])
 Amax= max (a, b, c)
 Bmin= min (a, b, c)
```

А вот к числу 20 никак не подберусь.
Думал что так:
     Csr!=Amax or Bmin
но выдает ошибку.
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Уточните ваш вопрос, в текущей формулировке совершенно не понятно, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Мне нужно в дальнейшем сравнить Amax, Bmin и Csr

Comment: Что должно находиться в Csr? И каким образом вы хотите их сравнивать?

Comment: В Csr должно быть среднее число. А сравнивать я потом хочу так: if (Bmin+Csr<Amax):
 print "triangle"
else:
 print "not triangle"

Comment: @Богдан: Что означает в Вашем случае слово "среднее"? `L = [a, b, c]`; `mean = average = sum(L)/len(L)`; `median = L[len(L)//2]` В данном [среднее значение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) равно [медиане](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_\(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0\))

Comment: @Богдан, условие `Csr!=Amax or Bmin` неправильно, т.к. сначала выполнится сравнение !=, а потом уже or. Правильно будет `Csr!=Amax and Csr!=Bmin` (если, конечно, я правильно понял, чего вы хотите)

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы найти, какое из трёх чисел большее, меньшее и среднее, можно сделать так:

```
l = sys.argv[1:4]              # кладём 3 аргумента командной строки в список
l.sort(key=lambda x: float(x)) # сортируем его
# так как элементы списка аргументов командной строки имеют стип string, 
# необходимо привести их к числовому типу, чтобы сортировать не в лексикографическом,
# а в числовом порядке
# для этого в качестве именованного аргумента key функции sort передаём анонимную функцию,
# осуществляющую такое преобразование
Bmin, Csr, Amax = l            # пользуемся приятнейшей фичей Python'а - множественным присваиванием
```

Или ещё короче:

```
Bmin, Csr, Amax = sorted(sys.argv[1:4], key=lambda x: float(x))
```

Дальше делаем с `Amax`, `Csr` и `Bmin` всё что душе угодно.

Comment: Большое спасибо, а можете, если не сложно, расшифровать человеческим языком ))) sys.argv - список аргументов командной строки, передаваемых сценарию Python. sys.argv[0] является именем скрипта (пустой строкой в интерактивной оболочке).

Comment: Извините, но не понимаю, почему когда я делаю: import sys

a=float(sys.argv[1])
b=float(sys.argv[2])
c=float(sys.argv[3])

Bmin, Csr, Amax = sorted(sys.argv[1:4])

print Bmin, Csr, Amax      и ввожу, например, 100, 60, 80, то их не расставляет по порядку )) Еще раз извините, но начинать изучать то  всегда тяжело )))

Comment: Прошу прощения за небольшую дезинормацию, поправил ответ. Аргументы командной строки имеют тип `string`, соответственно сортируются в лексикографическом порядке. Для того, чтобы отсортировать их ка числа, необходимо привести их к числовому типу. Для этого подойдёт параметр `key` функций `sort` и `sorted`. Он заставляет эти функции сортировать не непосредственно элементы списка, а результаты применения к ним какой-нибудь функции. В данном случае - приведения их к типу `float`.

Comment: Первый вариант (с пояснениями) выдает ошибку, а второй, что короче, работает. Большое спасибо

Comment: @fori1ton: первый фрагмент это ошибка на ошибке, поправьте пожалуйста. Не используйте `l` как имя, по возможности. Можно слово `numbers` вместо этого использовать: `numbers = map(float, sys.argv[1:]); numbers.sort(); Bmin, Cmean, Amax = numbers`

Comment: `key=lambda x: float(x)` можно заменить на `key=float`.

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего это сделать следующим образом:

1. При помощи встроенной функции map превращаем срез списка `sys.argv` в последовательность действительных чисел.
2. При помощи sorted получаем список отсортированных чисел из этой последовательности.
3. Пользуемся распаковкой последовательностей, чтобы получить отдельно три числа.

То есть:

```
Bmin, Csr, Amax = sorted(map(float, sys.argv[1:4]))
```

(пользуясь вашими обозначениями; а вообще лучше не надо переменные так называть).